# Google map not coming

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I have written a correct Google map code.Everything runs,but the map does not come.
i have used correct sha 1 machine key to generate the API key which i have.I have used different emulators and mobile phones,but its not coming.what may be the probable reason?
    xml code:

Comment: Check to added required permissions and key into manifest.xml file

Comment: Do you have any useful log? Any exception? Please post also the relevant code (at least the manifest file). Thanks.

Comment: Why are you so sure that is the correct one? Is the key for realease or debug, and what is your application -- debug or release? Add logcat when debugging, please.

Comment: How do i decide the key that i used is for debug or release?? I only know the debug key,how do we generate the release key??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to given those permission in manifiest

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="api key"/>
// android.apikey

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Please follow these steps:

1. Update the google play services in the SDK.
2. Manually uninstall the App from device and restart the device.
   i have tried it and its going perfectly bro

Also do one thing get the new api key to edited the new sh1 code from https://code.google.com/apis/console/

you can get your sh1 code from window- preference-android-buid

Comment: I tried these two ,infact i used oter permissions also,i have also used the correct api key,still i am not getting the map,only grey tiles are coming.

Comment: @user3201103 brother i have edited my answer please try it. i hope your problem will be resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the API Key you are using is incorrect.

In Order to get a valid API_KEY:

1) Go to Google APIS (https://cloud.google.com/console) and create a new project

2) Go to Apis & auth --> APIS and select "Google Maps Android API v2"

3) Go to Apis & auth --> Credentials and Create new key (for API access) "Key for Android applications"

4) Copy/paste the "API key" value to your manifest (as described Ravind)

5) If it works, then try adding restriction of the packages that are allowed

Comment: I did all the steps u told,still i am getting grey tiles,no map,what may be the other reason.I have generated the API key from the debug key given in eclipse->windows>prefrences>build